# Is this a good practice to write -> None everytime a function return nothing?

Tags: python

Is this a good practice to write `-> None` when a function does not return anything ?

```
def nothing() -> None:
   print("Hey I'm not returning anything!")
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @AMC I'm just asking. It's a good practice to ask questions about things you are didn't sure about.

Comment: I said nothing to the contrary, I'm asking if you know of any reasons why it wouldn't be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I would make a habit of this. If you're using type hints anyways, `-> None` is more consistent than leaving it blank.

If you change what the function returns as well, the type hint on the return will also help narrow down the cause of type warnings.

---

Previously, I had written:

> With a good IDE, you will also get warnings if you try to use the return value of `nothing`:
>
> ```
> # Warning: "Function 'nothing' doesn't return anything" (Pycharm)
> a = nothing()
> ```

Surprise surprise though, Pycharm is actually smart enough to infer that anyway even without the annotation.

With a dumber IDE, it may still make a difference in warnings produced, although I would expect that any IDE that's smart enough to make use of `-> None` would also be smart enough to statically infer `-> None`.

Comment: I'll note, I made a fairly major change after the voting had already been concluded. It turns out, Pycharm is smarter than I thought. Please re-evaluate your votes to reflect the change.